# Invalid arguments, Convert from Quaternion to Euler

Tags: quaternion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,
I used the section code for convert from Quaternion to Euler as :

```
void Nav::compassCallback(const sensor_msgs::Imu::ConstPtr& msg)
{
    // Convert quaternion to RPY.
    btQuaternion q;
    double roll, pitch, yaw;
    tf::quaternionMsgToTF(msg->orientation, q);
    btMatrix3x3(q).getRPY(roll, pitch, yaw);
    ROS_DEBUG("RPY = (%lf, %lf, %lf)", roll, pitch, yaw);
} // end compassCallback()
```

I get it from:
[link text](http://answers.ros.org/question/11545/plotprint-rpy-from-quaternion/)

but I got this error from Eclipse :

Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
void getRPY(float &, float &, float &, unsigned int)
'

I tried to used make on console on ROS and everything was good without error.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36977/invalid-arguments,-convert-from-quaternion-to-euler/) by [underwater](https://answers.ros.org/users/1303/underwater/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-06-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If everything worked when you compiled using make in the terminal, it's probably just a problem with Eclipse which you can safely ignore.

However, the code above won't work with Fuerte since TF now provides its own data types. The corresponding code looks like this:

```
void Nav::compassCallback(const sensor_msgs::Imu::ConstPtr& msg)
{
    // Convert quaternion to RPY.
    tf::Quaternion q;
    double roll, pitch, yaw;
    tf::quaternionMsgToTF(msg->orientation, q);
    tf::Matrix3x3(q).getRPY(roll, pitch, yaw);
    ROS_DEBUG("RPY = (%lf, %lf, %lf)", roll, pitch, yaw);
} // end compassCallback()
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7